# En mi código no puedo hacer una diferenciación por tamaño de imagen

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Estoy haciendo un programa que recorra una carpeta con imágenes y que después verifique que sean todas iguales de tamaño, y si aparece una más grande debe recortarla a la mitad.

```
for i in files_names:#aca lee la carpeta y impreme el tipo de dato
    image_path = input_images_path + "/" + i
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    shape_de_image = image.shape
    print(np.size(image))
```

En esta parte lee la carpeta sin problemas e imprime los tamaños de las fotos, todas las fotos menos una tiene el tamaño de (3056, 1988, 3) y la grande es más ancha (3056, 3975, 3).

Se me ocurrió que para cuando se encuentre la imagen grande la recorte y la exporte a otra carpeta.

```
#esta dentro del for de antes.
if np.size(image) == (3056, 3975, 3):#medida grande
        l1 = image[0:3056,0:1987]
        l2 = image[0:3056,1988:3975]
        cv2.imwrite(input_images_path + "/" + l1, l1)
        cv2.imwrite(input_images_path + "/" + l2, l2)
        print("yes")
```

Mi problema es que no entra la imagen grande (3056, 3975, 3), al `if`.

Comment: Sí estás usando mal `np.size()`, resulta que devuelve un entero que indica la cantidad de elementos en la matriz, no las respectivas dimensiones. Lo que quieres probablemente es usar `np.shape()`

Answer (score 1):

#### np.size()

`np.size(_ndarray_)` devuelve la cantidad de elementos en una matriz.

Ver ejemplo de la documentación [[Ir]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html)

```
# Matriz de dimensiones (3,5,2)
x = np.zeros((3, 5, 2), dtype=np.complex128)
```

Devuelve usando `x.size` o `np.size(x)`, `30`. Lo cual Indica el número de elementos `3*5*2=30`.

```py
np.size(x)    #  o >>x.size
```

Devuelve:

```
30
```

---

#### np.shape()

En cambio [`np.shape(_ndarray_)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) o [`x.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html), devuelven las dimensiones respectivas:

```
np.shape(x)    # o >>x.shape
```

Devuelve:

```
(3, 5, 2)
```